# How to have a multidimensional input rnn with legacy_seq2seq

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

For legacy_seq2seq, it just supports the input with a list of 2D Tensors.
If a model has more parameters for each inputs. says,
[[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]...] instead of [1, 2, 3, 4, ....], it cant use legacy_seq2seq to have batch methods.

So, how to implement a multidimensional input rnn in batch method with tensorflow?
Or it doesnt exist?

Answer (score 1):

Multi-dimensional RNNs are well supported in Tensorflow, but not added to the legacy seq2seq interface. Please use the current (dynamic_rnn) API and you'll see that multi-dimensional tensors work fine (there are even pre-made multi-dimensional RNN cells in contrib).